# Bulk mail using exchange server 2013 and 2016

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2003, exchange-server-2016

Hi i need help regarding number of mail sending per hour.

as earlier we were deployed exchange 2007 in our organization in that case we were sending approx 10000 mail par hour with 20kb of attachment
but now we have updated into exchange server 2013 and 2016

and we are able to send same mail only 700 approx mail per hour

please help how to increase limit up to 10000 per hour with 20kb of attachment with exchange server 2013 and 2016

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with MS Exchange 2010 Microsoft implemented a feature called "Throttling Policy" which control the "MessageRateLimit" as explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863577(v=exchg.150).aspx):

> The MessageRateLimit parameter specifies the number of messages per
>   minute that can be submitted to transport. For messages submitted
>   through the Mailbox server role (using Microsoft Outlook, Microsoft
>   Office Outlook Web App, Exchange ActiveSync, or Exchange Web
>   Services), this results in the deferral of messages until the quota
>   for the user is available. Specifically, messages appear in the Outbox
>   or Drafts folder for longer periods of time when users submit messages
>   at a rate greater than the MessageRateLimit parameter.
>
> For POP or IMAP clients submitting messages directly to transport
>   using SMTP, clients receive a transient error if they submit at a rate
>   that exceeds the MessageRateLimit parameter. Exchange attempts to
>   connect and send the messages at a later time.

So please follow the article [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863577(v=exchg.150).aspx), build a [new Throttling Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351045(v=exchg.150).aspx) an assign that to the users who should be able to send more emails.

**Please do NOT change the default throttling policy.**